# How to find all DOM elements with classes in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I'm creating a game right now using React and I need help with finding all elements with a certain className. This is a part of my code:

```
class FourthLine extends React.Component {
render() {
    const monsterList4 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        const monsterLine4 = <div className="four-line enemys"></div>
        monsterList4.push(monsterLine4)
    }
    return <div className="line-four">
        {monsterList4}
    </div>
   }
}
```

I want to get all elements with className "enemys" and read that enemys position x and position y. Is that even possible using React?

Comment: Its possible. Although usually not advised. You can use the componentDidMount lifecycle method and use regular JavaScript. If you needed a reference to the root element of your component, use the ref prop.

Comment: Ok thank you very much , that works great, i still need to find way with x and y position but that helps

Comment: Note that its 'enemies'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName('enemys')`